# Laravel/Cashier invoices() returns empty Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I've got a problem with the cashier package from Taylor (https://github.com/laravel/cashier). When I try to get the Invoices for a User the Object that is returned is Empty.
For information i've set up my cashier database columns into a membership table! And then set up the proper relationships.
I can charge the User if I do something like this:

```
$user->membership->subscription('1month')->create($token);
```

But if I want to get the invoices like so

```
$invoices = $user->membership->invoices();
```

it returns an empty Object.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Update:
Here`s the code from the Models:

```
User.php
public function membership() {
        return $this->hasOne('Membership');
    }
```

and

```
Membership.php
class Membership extends \Eloquent implements BillableInterface {

    use BillableTrait;

   /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];

    public function user_membership() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Post more code (relationship of models).

Comment: Updated the question with the code from my Models

Answer (score 5):

If you are pulling it as a JSON or similar, this can be a useful snippet to return from your controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user->hasStripeId()) {
            $invoices = $user->invoices()->map(function($invoice) {
                return [
                    'date' => $invoice->date()->toFormattedDateString(),
                    'total' => $invoice->total,
                    'download' => '/user/download/invoice/' . $invoice->id,
                ];
            });
        } else {
            $invoices = [];
        }

        return [ 'invoices' => $invoices ];
    }
```

Tested in Cashier v7.x

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Laravel 5.1, if you checkout \laravel\cashier\src\Laravel\Cashier\Invoice.php you can see all the methods available on the Invoice object.

You have to loop through the $this->user->invoices() object to use the methods, but if you're looking for a verbose dump of the invoice data you can call getStripeInvoice().

This dumps all the data related to an invoice..

```
    $invoices_object = $this->user->invoices();
    $invoices = [];

    foreach($invoices_object as $invoice) {
        array_push($invoices, $invoice->getStripeInvoice() );
    }
    return $invoices;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone also struggling with this, I found that just returning $invoices will show a blank json array, but if you pass $invoices to a view, and use a foreach loop it will work.

Ex:
This returns a blank array

```
$invoices = $user->invoices();

return $invoices
```

The following will return a value even though it appears blank in the original json return.

```
$invoices = $user->invoices();

foreach ($invoices as $invoice)

{

$test = $invoice->dateString();

}

return $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't using laravel Cashier as such. I'm using stripe and their API is simple and easy to understand.

I resolved using

```
\Stripe\Invoice::all(['customer' => $this->user->stripe_id]);
```

The stripe package is included with Cashier so no extra vendor files needed

This is especially helpful if you want to post the data to your js frontend app.

Laravel Cashier expects you to build views in blade with the given functions provided in the Invoice item classwhich is great if your using laravel as the full MVC not so great if your using as an api so it doesn't seem to do pre-building the Array of objects.

Comment: Saved my day, this is much more usable than the Cashier method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in `subscription()` before calling `invoices()`

`$user->membership()->subscription()->invoices();`